# How can I embed an EXE File inside a VC++ exe program

Tags: visual-c++

I want to hide my exe file, it is VB code, so I thought I can but it inside a vc++ code and then I can call it from VC++ code like run(myfile.exe) or execute(myfile.exe).
But I do not how can I add it inside a VC++!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it using [[MS.Docs]: Introduction to Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/menurc/introduction-to-resources).

There are 2 stages that you need to work on:

- Build time: when building your *C++* application, you must instruct *VStudio* to include (embed) the *VB* executable (I named it *resource.exe*) into the project output (*C++* executable that it generates) as a resource; (of course) for that you need to have the *VB* executable at build time
- Run time: your *C++* application must be able to get the resource from itself, save it into a file, and execute it

Here is a prototype that I tested (and it works). There are 3 files that you need to include in your *VStudio 10.0 (2010)* project:

- *res.h* - just a file with constant definitions to be included by both other files. Include it under *Header Files*

  ```c
  #define EXE_NAME "resource.exe"
  #define RES_TYPE_UNQUOTED RAW
  #define RES_NAME_UNQUOTED EXECUTABLE
  ```
- *exe.rc* - this is the resource file (as simplified as possible). Include it under *Resource Files*. **Note**: trying to edit it from *VStudio* will fail since the resource editor expects the file to contain some crap (inserted by default by *VStudio*).

  ```c
  #include "res.h"
  RES_NAME_UNQUOTED RES_TYPE_UNQUOTED EXE_NAME
  ```
- *main.c* - the main code file. Include it under *Source Files*. It loads the resource from itself, saves it into a file and then attempts to execute that file. I used the commented code for debugging, it's no longer necessary, but I left it there anyway. **Note** that this is just an example, the code could be written much better (in terms of e.g. error handling, resource organization, ...), I focused to have something working.

  ```c
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <Windows.h>
  #include "res.h"

  #define _QUOTE(X) #X
  #define QUOTE(X) _QUOTE(X)
  #define RES_TYPE QUOTE(RES_TYPE_UNQUOTED)
  #define RES_NAME QUOTE(RES_NAME_UNQUOTED)

  /*
  #define NULL_STR "null"

  BOOL CALLBACK EnumResNameProc(_In_opt_ HMODULE hModule, _In_ LPCTSTR lpszType, _In_ LPTSTR lpszName, _In_ LONG_PTR lParam) {
      if (IS_INTRESOURCE(lpszName))
          printf("    ResourceName(int): [%d]\n", lpszName);
      else {
          printf("    ResourceName(str): [%s]\n", lpszName ? lpszName : NULL_STR);
          printf("    Resource addr: %08X\n", (long)FindResource(NULL, lpszName, lpszType));
      }
      return TRUE;
  }

  BOOL CALLBACK EnumResTypeProc(_In_opt_ HMODULE hModule, _In_ LPTSTR lpszType, _In_ LONG_PTR lParam) {
      if (IS_INTRESOURCE(lpszType))
          printf("  ResourceType(int): [%d]\n", lpszType);
      else
          printf("  ResourceType(str): [%s]\n", lpszType ? lpszType : NULL_STR);
      EnumResourceNames(NULL, lpszType, EnumResNameProc, lParam);
      return TRUE;
  }
  //*/

  int main() {
      HANDLE fp = NULL;
      HRSRC res = NULL;
      HGLOBAL global = NULL;
      char *buf = NULL;
      DWORD size = 0, written = 0;
      int ret = -1;

  /*
      EnumResourceTypes(NULL, EnumResTypeProc, NULL);
      printf("[%s][%s]\n", RES_NAME, RES_TYPE);
  //*/
      if ((res = FindResource(NULL, RES_NAME, RES_TYPE)) == NULL) {
          printf("FindResource error: %d\n", GetLastError());
          return 1;
      }
      if ((global = LoadResource(NULL, res)) == NULL) {
          printf("LoadResource error: %d\n", GetLastError());
          return 2;
      }
      if ((size = SizeofResource(NULL, res)) == 0) {
          printf("SizeofResource error: %d\n", GetLastError());
          return 3;
      }
      if ((buf = (char*)LockResource(global)) == NULL) {
          printf("LockResource error: %d\n", GetLastError());
          return 4;
      }
      if ((fp = CreateFile(EXE_NAME, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL , NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
          printf("CreateFile error: %d\n", GetLastError());
          return 5;
      }
      if (WriteFile(fp, buf, size, NULL, NULL) == FALSE) {
          printf("WriteFile error: %d\n", GetLastError());
          CloseHandle(fp);
          return 5;
      }
      CloseHandle(fp);
      ret = system(EXE_NAME);
      printf("system returned %d\n", ret);
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: can you please send me the source code and files by a link, I would be grateful

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how to do that. But all you need to do is to create the 3 files that I enumerated and copy/paste the corresponding code blocks that I posted into them.

Comment: Ok, for Dropbox I have to download a funky app, which I don't want to, and for Google Drive I need some contact details to share with.

Comment: please send by email.  moneejkoo3@gmail.com

Comment: Done. Probably this would have been the best method to begin with. Anyway I'm having trouble understanding why this step was necessary, since the files content that I emailed is right here in the solution in the `code blocks` areas (everything you needed to do, was to copy it and paste it into the files opened in a text editor (or IDE) on your PC).

Comment: I did not receive  please send me again at monnejkoo9@gmail.com

Comment: Invalid address. Seriously, this is getting beyond ridiculous.

Comment: so sorry, please send moneejkoo9@gmail.com  I forget 'e' after 'n' so sorry

Comment: I figured out it's a typo. Anyway, I sent it.